# Uniqueness of limiting functions

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

Let $\{f_n\},\ f_n:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the limiting function, $f(x)$, of the sequence satisfies
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx = 0.
$$

Is this limiting function unique?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If $f$ is the limit is the sequence $\{f_n\}$, then yes, it is unique. Is the problem supposed to read "suppose $f$ is a function such that ___; prove that $f$ is unique"?

Comment: Are all of these functions continuous? If not the modification of $f$ at a single value will suffice to demonstate the lack of uniqueness.

Comment: if the $f_n$ are continuous (or bounded), hence if each $f_n \in L^2([a,b])$ then the limit $f$ if it exists is unique in the $L^2([a,b])$ sense ($\approx$ the almost everywhere sense)

Comment: @Chanler The question does not specify whether they are continuous or not. I'm not sure what you mean by "modification of $f$ at a single value," could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The existence of the integral seems to indicate that $f_{n}(x)$ and $f(x)$
are square integrable. The $f_{n}(x)$ need not be continuous, they can be
simple functions
\begin{equation*}
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k}c_{nk}\chi _{M_{k}}(x),\;M_{k}\cap M_{l}=0,\;k\neq l,\;\cup
M_{k}=[a,b]
\end{equation*}
where $\chi _{M_{k}}(x)$ is the characteristic function for the (measurable)
set $M_{k}$. Any $L^{2}$-function is the limit in $L^{2}$-norm of such a
sequence in the almost everywhere (ae) sense. In this sense $f(x)$ is unique
provided it exists which seems to be assumed. In general it need not have
any continuity properties. Note that this result is somewhat more general
than the statement by  user1952009 who assumed continuity or boundedness of
the $f_{n}$'s.

Answer (score 0):

If we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b|f_n-g|dx=0$, we get that $\int_{a}^{b}|f-g|dx\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b|f-f_n|dx+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b|f_n-g|dx=0$. So $|f-g|$ is a positive function of vanishing integral. This means that if $f, g$, and thus $|f-g|$ are continuous, then $f=g$. But in general $f$ and $g$ can differ on a set of measure zero. For for example, let $f_n=0$, and $f=0$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $g(x)=x$ else, Then since $\int_a^b |g(x)|dx=0$, we have that $f_n\to f$ and $f_n\to g$.